# Binding class with VueJS and Props

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an Vue component called `Avatar.vue`, for create a avatar img defined by props passing by the user, the parameter `imgType` define if the user want use a img with radius border or not, this is the code

```
<template>
<div>
    <img
            :class="{'img-circle': isCircle()}"
            src="./assets/defaultImg"
            :height="imgHeight"
            :width="imgWidth"
    >
</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
    props: ['imgHeight', 'imgWidth', 'imgType'],
    methods: {
        isCircle: function () {
            return this.imgType.toString() === 'circle';
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.img-circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>
```

And this is the HTML caller

```
<div>
     <avatar-img
      :imgHeight="100"
      :imgWidth="100"
      :imgType="circle">
     </avatar-img>
</div>
```

But when i call this component the parameter `imgType` this return a error `Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined"` 
I`m sorry if i`m not explain very well but i try my best

Comment: Why are you calling `toString()` on a `String`?  Will `imgType` ever **not** be a `String`?  Additionally, is `imgType` ever populated asynchronously?

Comment: If i remove `toString()` the `type of this.imgType` return `undefined`

Comment: It's trying to use `circle` as a variable.  Put `circle` in single quotes:  `:imgType=" 'circle' "` or remove the colon: `imgType="circle"`

Comment: The `imgType` is populated when the page load

Comment: Thanks @zero298 works for me without the colon, can you answer the post to be closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your binding is trying to interpret `circle` as a variable.  Either remove the colon (since there doesn't need to be a binding):

```
<div>
     <avatar-img
      :imgHeight="100"
      :imgWidth="100"
      imgType="circle">
     </avatar-img>
</div>
```

Or put `circle` in single quotes so it is interpreted as a String (Spaces added for emphasis):

```
<div>
     <avatar-img
      :imgHeight="100"
      :imgWidth="100"
      :imgType=" 'circle' "> 
     </avatar-img>
</div>
```

Consider the following:

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    "avatar-img": {
      props: ['imgHeight', 'imgWidth', 'imgType'],
      methods: {
        isCircle: function() {
          return this.imgType === 'circle';
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <avatar-img :img-height="100" :img-width="100" img-type="circle" inline-template>
    <div>
      <img :class="{'img-circle': isCircle()}" src="./assets/defaultImg" :height="imgHeight" :width="imgWidth">
    </div>
  </avatar-img>
</div>
```